# Gitlab.com Webhooks - Triggers and Request IPs

Tags: git, api, continuous-integration, gitlab

I can't find enough documentation on the gitlab.com Webhooks. The following questions have come up trying to use it in order to autopull on a commit:

1. Is the following documentation current on the point that Gitlab does not trigger webhook on web interface commits? Github does that and without it I have to say webhooks are rather useless since people can change the repo without the webhook consumer being notified. http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/project_services/bamboo.html#complete-these-steps-in-gitlab ; If the answer to this is *yes* then please ignore my second question, since I will have to give up on gitlab for now.
2. What IP addresses does gitlab.com use to send webhook requests? For github there is this nice API on `https://api.github.com/meta --> hooks` that tells me the hook IP - I couldn't find something like that for gitlab, does this kind of API exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A Gitlab web interface push seems to trigger the webhook (you can test that with e.g. http://requestb.in/)
2. The sender IP address can also be checked with http://requestb.in/ - in my case it was 104.209.177.7; not sure if it will always be the same IP though

Comment: yep, that worked. Thanks a lot! I've also opened up the following issue on gitlab.com: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/13478